# What are the rules about using Bounty Messages to evade comment locks?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, moderation, bounties

The comments on [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/57202/19301) were locked by yannis due to excessive off-topic discussion and debate. Recently, a user posted a bounty on the question, but the bounty message has nothing to do with what the user is looking for in a answer, but is instead a comment attacking Biden as stupid and a radical and talking about Trump's new campaign ads.

Since users are spending their own rep to post them, there's usually a lot of leeway given to these messages, but in this case it seems pretty clear that the user is simply using this to get around the comment lock to their post their off-topic comment.

Is this allowed? If not, is there something that the Mods can do about it? If so, what *are* the rules for what should be put in a bounty message?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The purpose of the bounty message is to explain the expectations from the bounty winner. It is not a substitute for comments. It is a lot more visible than regular comments, and cannot be flagged, upvoted or replied to. Using it as a comment is an abuse of the feature, intentional or not.

I removed the bounty.

If the user is interested in investing their reputation towards a more detailed answer, they are free to set a new bounty with a more appropriate message.

Comment: It looks like *three* bounties were added and removed in the post history. That makes this answer seem overly simplifying what happened.

Comment: Actually "simplifying" is charitable. We already know you removed the bounties. Why? Is that an exception, or do you want to propose a site rule?

Comment: @frеdsbend I only ever saw the first notice, but the fact that the user reposted the bounty 2 times after having it removed by a mod makes it even worse. The first time could have just been a misunderstanding, the second and third times are clearly an attempt to break the rules. This makes the 1 week suspension the user received make a lot more sense, so thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @frеdsbend The answer is focused on the first bounty. I'm afraid I can't give any details - other than what's already publicly available - about what happened next.